# Receiving import error when running basic Python app in only some locations

Tags: python, installation

This is a novice question for sure, but I'd appreciate any help!

I'm receiving an error when running a python script that imports an installed module. This seems to be for any module, but for the sake of an example, here's a super simple Flask app that throws this error upon being run:

**ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask'**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's the weird bits.
This file will not run (it throws the error) if it's saved in say:
/Users/my_user/desktop/folder/subfolder

But **will** run if it's saved:
/Users/my_user/desktop

So clearly this means flask is installed. I've confirmed this as well by running `flask --version` in Terminal.

My question is this: Is there anything that I'd need to change in my configuration to allow a file saved anywhere to be able to import modules?

I'm not sure if this will clarify things or confuse things further, but I was able to run Flask Apps from /Users/my_user/desktop/folder/subfolder last week. To the best of my understanding, nothing in my configuration changed recently so I'm not sure why this error just popped up.

Happy to provide more info if needed. Thanks for the help, community.

Answer (score 0):

Is your interpreter configured correctly?

(if you're using PyCharm for example)
File > settings > Project:your_project > Project Interpreter

you should see a list of packages along with your version and the latest version. If Flask is not in the first column click the + button on the top right and search for Flask (or whatever package you need) and click install.

More information: [Configure a Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)

Comment: Ah, good lead. I discovered I'm using the standard cpython as an Interpreter by doing the following:
```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.python_implementation()
'CPython'
```
I'll look into this more. Thanks!